# Am I geting a structure copy here?

Tags: c++, reference, overwrite

Here is a fake code sample

```
vector<Fred> gFred;
{
    // init gFred

    Fred &fred = gFred[0];

    size_t z = 0;
    do
    {
        fred = gFred[z];

        // do odd processing with fred

        z++;
    }
    while (fred.lastElementInSet == 0);
}
```

The thing that caught my attention was the fact that gFred[0] was being overwritten.
This leads me to think that rather than init fred as a reference to a new element,

```
fred = gFred[z];
```

What is actually happening is that gFred[1] is overwriting gFred[0].

I'm thinking the correct thing to do here, is whap myself upsida head a few times, and turn this into a pointer implementation and move on with my life.

Have I diagnosed this correctly? or do I need more education?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are getting a structure copy there. References cannot be rebound, i.e., they stay the same once they are initialized.

And your solution is also appropriate. Dunno about smacking yourself in the head though.

Comment: Now, if you move the declaration of &fred inside the do loop ( Fred &fred = gFred[z]; ) it should work as you expect, making fred an alias for gFred[z];

Answer (score 3):

One way of looking at references is to think of them as implicitly de-referenced pointers. Simply put, they are pointers, but you can use the normal variable access syntax to use them

```
Fred &fred = gFred[0];
```

This creates a reference to the first element of your vector gFred. (Incidentally, do you have anything inside this?) The compiler will do something like this:

```
Fred *pFred = &gFred[0];
```

Now, when you do:

```
fred = gFred[z];
```

the compiler will actually do something like this:

```
*pFred = gFred[z];
```

which translated stands as:

```
gFred[0] = gFred[z];
```

And you are doing this `N` times, if you have N elements to start off in your `vector`.

If you are trying to initialize all elements of your `vector` try this constructor:

```
vector(size_type n, const T& t)
```

where,

```
n = size of vector
t = gFred[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

With the code you posted (and assuming the Fred type is a POD), gFred[0] is being written over and will end up containing a copy of wahatever was in gFred[z] for the last z.

You could switch to using a pointer implementation, or you could scope the reference more closely:

```
{    
    size_t z = 0;
    do
    {
        Fred &fred = gFred[z];
        // do odd processing with fred
        z++;
    }
    while (fred.lastElementInSet == 0);
}
```

Comment: Yep. that is a viable option. +1
I don't like it as well, since evil msvc 6 closes fred in the watch window, ever time it is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you give, `fred` is always referencing `gFred[0]`. If you want the `fred` reference to change with each iteration of the loop, remove the line `Fred &fred=gFred[0];` . Then replace `fred = gFred[z];` with `Fred &fred = gFred[z]`. This way, you reinitialize the `fred` reference each time the loop executes.

Answer (score 0):

the compiled mechanism is explained by dirkgently's answer, while the underlying explanation is MSN's one ("References cannot be rebound").

maybe it's easier to read this way:

if

```
ptr = &xxx;
```

means that the content of `ptr` is the address of `xxx`, then

```
&fred = gFred[0];
```

means that the *address* of `fred` is set to point to `gFred[0]`. IOW, `fred` is now an alias to `gFred[0]`.  that's why doing `fred = xxx` overwrites `gFred[0]`